# How can I convert "letter emojis" in a string to regular letters (english)? in python

Tags: python, string, utf-8, emoji, lib

I would like to know how can I convert "letter emojis" such as '' and '' into their regular letter fonts (the original ASCII for English Alphabet) in a string in Python.

For example: 
**''** should become **'Rotem'** and
**'ëⓁᴏ'** should become **'HeLlo'**
etc...

Thanks for all answering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to have all cases.

My attempt:

```
import unicodedata

s = ''
s = 'ëⓁᴏ'

def normalize_compatibily(s):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s)

def remove_accents(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
                   if unicodedata.category(c).startswith('L'))

print(s)
s = normalize_compatibily(s)
print(s)
s = remove_accents(s)
print(s)
```

solve some cases.

Unfortunately in the case of *U+1D0F LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL O*, there is no data in Unicode database, which could help us.  Not really, the Unicode name `unicodedata.name()` could help, e.g. with regex, but this would mean to look all similar characters, and it will fails where the letter is not in the name.

But there is an other table (not on main database) about *[confusable characters](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp)*, and so there is a Python library:
https://pypi.org/project/confusables/, see last example.

You may need to mix both methods, and eventually adding some new characters that are not so confusable nor related, but anyway used to replace other characters.